# Positioning div classes with images in a row?

Tags: css, html

So here's what it looks like:

http://www.whybaguio.com/php/visit/attractions.php

How can I put on three images per row without using the float element. If I use the float, the background of the wrapper gets removed :( I have no idea how to fix this, I tried using the display: inline, using of span instead of div but nothing didn't work :(

Please help!

Thaanks.

Comment: The background "gets removed" because all your elements are floating and therefore there is no height to the background element left.  Try using a `clear`ed element at the end or use a `clearfix` hack on the container element.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#wrapperatt` div as the floated children elements are out of the document flow causing the container to collapse - [this is pretty typical float behaviour](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow) and is why you see the background disappear.